# "fatal error 'ncurses/ncurses.h' file not found" during `brew install cmake`

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

I'm struggling to install cmake to OSX 10.8 (mountain lion)

```
$ brew install -v cmake
```

However, I got the following error.

```
[  2%] Built target cmcompress
In file included from /tmp/cmake20160412-70643-1kq4xsy/cmake-3.4.0/Source/CursesDialog/form/fld_arg.c:33:
In file included from /tmp/cmake20160412-70643-1kq4xsy/cmake-3.4.0/Source/CursesDialog/form/form.priv.h:34:
/tmp/cmake20160412-70643-1kq4xsy/cmake-3.4.0/Source/CursesDialog/form/form.h:46:12: fatal error: 'ncurses/ncurses.h' file not found
#  include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
           ^
1 error generated.
```

I've installed `ncurses` via `brew install ncurses` after receiving the above error. But, the error message `'ncurses/ncurses.h' file not found` still occurs.

Please help to resolve this issue...

#### Update

According to `locate` command, there are multiple `ncurses.h` files in my file system:

```
$ locate ncurses.h
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/ncurses/ncurses.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/ncurses.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/ncurses.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/ncurses.h
/opt/local/include/ncurses/ncurses.h
/opt/local/include/ncursesw/ncurses.h
/sw/include/ncurses.h
/usr/include/ncurses.h
```

#### Update 2

This resolve the issue:

```
$ ln -s /opt/local/include/ncurses /usr/include
```

because the following paths are searched by c compiler

```
$ clang++ -x c -v -E /dev/null
...
/usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
...
```

Comment: WRT update #2: omg no.  You are really messing up your system.  You do know you can use `-I` to add an include directory, right?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yeah... I agree adding symbolic link will mess up my system... Is it possible to add -I option even when installing via `brew install`?

Comment: I don't know TBH I've always thought homebrew was crap, so I use macports.  Looks like that port (or whatever they call it) is broken as it depends on ncurses and yet it didn't automatically install it.  I would get help from the homebrew forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Macports version, however you are using homebrew, and `/opt/local/include` is unlikely to be an include directory:

```
/opt/local/include/ncurses/ncurses.h
```

And none of the others are in an `ncurses` sub-directory.

So that all makes sense.

Perhaps the home brew thing is broken? Stick to Macports.